# Comparison between a pointer and integer problem

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I have a conditional statement that I need some help with the syntax:

```
if (mySegment.selectedSegmentIndex == 0 && [[[dict objectForKey:[keys objectAtIndex:row]] objectAtIndex:0] == 8 ) {
NSLog(@"test");
}
```

I'm getting a `comparison between a pointer and integer problem` warning. I need a conditional based on a selection of a segment value and then compare that to a value returned from a dictionary object.

thanks for any help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

convert `dict` value into integer and then compare

try this:

```
if (mySegment.selectedSegmentIndex == 0 && [[[dict objectForKey:[keys objectAtIndex:row]] objectAtIndex:0]intValue] == 8 ) {
NSLog(@"test");
}
```

Comment: worked perfectly! thanks. i couldn't figure out where to put the "intValue"

Answer (score 6):

NSDictionary objects can contain only NSNumber instances, and not primitive scalar types like integer. That's why you're getting the warning.

Try this line instead:

```
if (mySegment.selectedSegmentIndex == 0 && [[[[dict objectForKey:[keys objectAtIndex:row]] objectAtIndex:0] integerValue] == 8 ) {
...
}
```

Note that I've added a call to `integerValue` on object returned from array.

Comment: Oh great i totally forget the method calls and jump into c syntax. I am thinking if i should delete my answer or let it be. +1 for you though.

Answer (score 2):

`[[[dict objectForKey:[keys objectAtIndex:row]] objectAtIndex:0]` returns a object which has to be typecast to int before comparing to 8 which is integer.

`((int)[[[dict objectForKey:[keys objectAtIndex:row]] objectAtIndex:0])== 8` should do the trick for you.